# Segmentation fault on rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, segmentation-fault, android-rom

Is anybody can tell me what's going on? All rails command return segmentation fault, I tried to find solution on google but I didn't find any. I can'nt root my smartphone. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: You need to be more explicit. The best advice I can give you is an attempted reinstallation via this guide: https://mbobin.me/ruby/2017/02/25/ruby-on-rails-on-android.html